# Angularjs switch statement

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I am fetching few values from my backend and assigning then to my scope variables in angular controller. for one of the variables I get the values between 1 till 7 and depending on the which number it is I want to do something like following:

```
.success(function(response){

            $scope.initial_data=response;

            angular.forEach($scope.initial_data, function(item){

            $scope.exercise_id=item.exercise_type;
            alert($scope.exercise_id) // This gives me either 1 or any number till 7   

            switch($scope.exercise_id){
              case '1':
                    alert("1");
                    break;
              case '2':
                    alert("2");
                    break;
              default:
                    alert("Default");            

            }
```

However, this piece of code for switch statement always alerts gives me *Default*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `exercise_id` is a number, you are switching on strings - `'1'` isnt the same as  `1`!

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks!